# Angular MatAccordion is displayed flat by default

Tags: angular, accordion, mat-expansion-panel

I'm using mat-accordion component in my application, however even though it is clearly stated in the documentation here -> https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#expansion-overview the default displayMode is border + raised. When I run the example code for expansion panel from the link above in my app, it shows as flat. When I try to explicitly set displayMode property to 'default' it shows as flat. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui Well the problem is there it works :) It doesn't in my app and it's already quite bulky to try to migrate it to stackblitz

Comment: I would compare Angular and Angular material versions or tried to create a simple expansion panel in your app and see how it works

Comment: @yurzui Yep, I literally took the code from the docs example and added it to my app, it's flat. What I have is @angular/material@13.2.0.

Comment: I just created a project from scratch and tried the panel and it works fine, so I suppose it's something in the styling that is overriding how expansion panel looks?

Comment: Try commenting some parts of your application and you should be able to find the cause

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something else is overwriting your css. It can happen when css is bleeding from other components if they use `::ng-deep, :host` etc. The use of `!important` even on encapsulated styles might be overwriting. This is just a guess.

This adds the raised effect. Add this to your component stylesheet and observe if normal visuals return.

```css
.mat-expansion-panel:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]) {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px #0003,0 2px 2px #00000024,0 1px 5px #0000001f !important;
}
```

If they return then something is indeed overwriting material default css. Find the problem and fix it.

Comment: Thanks, this helps indeed. However I can't understand what can possibly override this. I barely even have CSS in my project and all I have are custom classes, I didn't override any of the existing ones. Can it be because I'm using both bootstrap and angular material?